# What protections are put in place to prevent rootkits from getting ring 0 access?

Tags: operating-systems, rootkits

I've been learning about [What is a rootkit?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/what-is-a-rootkit) As well as rootkit building and general system architecture. I have read that there are "User mode" rootkits that run in ring 3. But these aren't the highest level of control over a system. The holy grail of a rootkit is to get ring 0 control?

What protects the kernel and system from a rootkit getting ring 0 access?

Comment: Wiki helps to explain: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rootkit#Kernel_mode

Comment: In terms of "highest level of control over a system", be sure to also check Hypervisor level rootkits from @schroeder's link, where the rootkit "promotes" the operating into a virtual machine while it is running. After that, only the rootkit has physical access to the environment, the OS has just access to the virtualized environment presented by the rootkit...